# how to test if index exists in array

Tags: bash, array

I'm writing a Git Bash utility that copies a project folder from one location to another.  There are multiple destinations to which the user may want to copy the project, though only one location per execution of the script is permitted.  Here is the logic thus far -

```
#!/bin/bash

# declare and initialize variables
source="/z/files/development/xampp/code/htdocs/Project7"

targets[0]="/z/files/development/xampp/code/htdocs/test/$(date +'%Y_%m_%d')"
targets[1]="/c/users/knot22/desktop/temp_dev/$(date +'%Y_%m_%d')"

# display contents of variables to user
echo "source " $source
echo -e "\nchoice \t target location"

for i in "${!targets[@]}"; do
  echo -e "$i \t ${targets[$i]}" 
done

echo

# prompt user for a target
read -p "Enter target's number for this copy operation: " target
```

So far, so good.  Next I'd like to write an `if` statement that checks whether or not the value the user entered for `target` is a valid index in `targets`.  In PHP it would be `array_key_exists($target, $targets)`.  What is the equivalent in Bash?

Comment: `source` is a reserved keyword. You shoulnt use it a as a variable name.

Comment: @Daniele are you sure about that?  I know it's a built-in command name, but that shouldn't prevent it being used as a variable name.  The manual says that the reserved words are `!`, `case`, `coproc`, `do`, `done`, `elif`, `else`, `esac`, `fi`, `for`, `function`, `if`, `in`, `select`, `then`, `until`, `while`, `{`, `}`, `time`, `[[` and `]]`.  Also, use as a variable is perfectly legitimate for a reserved word - the contexts in which they are reserved are as command names and a couple of other places where only `in` or `do` are allowed.

Comment: I haven't noticed any strange behavior using `source` as a variable name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the array element is not null/empty with:

```
expr='^[0123456789]+$'
if [[ $target =~ $expr && -n "${targets[$target]}" ]]; then
    echo yes
else
    echo no
fi
```

You also have to check if the response is an integer since people can reply to the read prompt with a string which will evaluate to zero and therefore give you the first element in your array.

You may also want to consider using [select](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) here:

```
#!/bin/bash

# declare and initialize variables
source="/z/files/development/xampp/code/htdocs/Project7"

targets[0]="/z/files/development/xampp/code/htdocs/test/$(date +'%Y_%m_%d')"
targets[1]="/c/users/knot22/desktop/temp_dev/$(date +'%Y_%m_%d')"

select i in "${targets[@]}" exit; do
    [[ $i == exit ]] && break
    echo "$i which is number $REPLY"
done
```

Comment: `select` is an excellent suggestion.

Comment: `select` is certainly more concise.  However, it lists sequential integers starting at 1 whereas the original approach listed the array index values of 0, 1.  Is there a way to get `select` to display the array index values instead (without doing " - 1" incase there are non sequential array index values)?

Comment: @knot22: But do you even need the index values anymore since the array element selected will be represented by `$i` within the select statement.  So you could just do `cp "$i" ...` instead of referencing the array again at all.

Comment: @knot22, if you really really want to work with indices, the foolproof way to validate the user's input would be for-loop: `valid=false; for idx in "${!targets[@]}"; do if [[ "$idx" == "$target" ]]; then valid=true; break; fi; done; if ! "$valid"; then echo "invalid entry"; fi`

Comment: Good call for trying to sanitise the input before using it as an arithmetic expression, but you can't use `[0-9]` for that, you need `[0123456789]` instead. For instance, in Ubuntu 20.04, and with the `th_TH` Thai locale enabled, if the script is called in an environment with the wrong variables, for instance with `env LC_ALL=th_TH $'\xf3=a[$(reboot)]'`, if the user enters the 0xF3 byte at that prompt (Thai digit 3 in the TIS-620 charset used by that locale, also considered as *alpha* so as a valid variable name by bash), that will reboot.

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks for that.  I'm not married to working with indices, I have a certain level of familiarity having worked with them in PHP.

Comment: Thank you @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: @jesse_b After some more experimenting, I see what you mean by not needing the index value anymore when using `select`.  Nice!  I ended up using `select` for this script instead of indices followed by an `if` that checks if `$i` is null/empty.

Comment: @jesse_b I'd like to read up on `-n`.  So far, no success on finding where its documented though.  Wondering what man page that would be under.  Any chance you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: @knot22: You can find it here (also the same link Glenn posted in his answer): https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR This answer is wrong, but I explain why.

---

I wrote:

> You could use `-v`
>
> ```bsh
> if [[ -v targets[$target] ]]; then ...
> ```
>
> Documented in [6.4 Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions)

**But that's wrong.**

In a numerically indexed array, the index is evaluated as an arithmetic expression. In an arithmetic expression, "bare" strings are handled as *shell variables* and if the variable is empty or unset, it is handled as the value zero.

Demo:

```bsh
targets=(zero one two)

target=2
[[ -v targets[target] ]] && echo "${targets[target]}" || echo n
# ==> two

target="x"
[[ -v targets[target] ]] && echo "${targets[target]}" || echo n
# ==> zero
```

But if there is a variable with the same *name* as the *value* of `$target`, then:

```bsh
x=1
[[ -v targets[target] ]] && echo "${targets[target]}" || echo n
# ==> one
```

Comment: This seems to work correctly for integer entries but if a letter is entered, it returns the value in `targets[0]`.

Comment: And if someone enters `$(reboot)` at that `read` prompt, that will reboot.

Comment: You could still use the same hacky workaround I used to check if it's an integer first.  I was not aware that -v even existed.  I guess that wouldn't work in the case of an associative array though.